# set ng-required value depending on scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `username` element of which i want to set `ng-required` value to `true/false` depending on another java-script variable e.g. '`isMainSite`'

We can write expression inside `ng-required` attribute.

Lets say my scope has folllowing variable into it

```
$scope.User = {
    emailAddress: '',
    emailAddressConfirm: '',
    username: '',
    password: '',
    passwordConfirm: ''
}
```

Username element

```
<input type="text" class="textbox shareinput" ng-model="User.username" ng-required="true"
name="username" tabindex="18" ng-class="{'has-error': submitted && formUserInfo.username.$invalid}"
onclick="$(this).focus();" maxlength="20" />
```

How can i modify `ng-required` attribute to meet my requirements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the variable `isMainSite` in your controller, then use it with the `ngRequired` directive.

*HTML*

```
ng-required="isMainSite"
```

In controller, set the value of variable as per requirement

```
$scope.isMainSite = false;
```

Comment: is there any way doing this without adding into scope variable ?

Comment: @Shaggy, this is simplest. Why cant you add to `$scope`?